# Redo changes in oracle db after commit

Tags: database, oracle, oracle10g

Is there any method to redo changes in Oracle db after commit? Please can anyone guide me

P.s. Oracle version I'm using is 10.1.1.8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flashback queries can help. Have a look [at this article](http://www.orafaq.com/node/50) which briefs you on the details about it.

> Flashback query allows a user to view the data quickly and easily the way it was at a particular time in the past, even when it is modified and committed, be it a single row or the whole table.

Oracle documentation on Flashback query is [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_fl.htm).

Comment: thanks. there is another interesting link i found !

http://oracleflash.com/25/Using-Oracle-LogMiner-to-undo-incorrectly-committed-changes.html

Comment: interesting. You should post that as an alternative answer too, @HashimR

Comment: yeah but...I'm new so i don't have enough privileges :)

Comment: @HashimR you can post it later as well.

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting link i found.

http://oracleflash.com/25/Using-Oracle-LogMiner-to-undo-incorrectly-committed-changes.html